# ContainerViewController addChildViewController with wired bottom margin (64px)

Tags: ios

When I use a uiviewcontroller as containerViewController and add childVC with the method "addChildViewController:".Then, there will be a bottom margin, such as the image.I handle this problem with replacing "addChildViewController:" with "willMoveToParentViewController:",but still don't know why.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// 默认显示第一个控制器
[self displayContentController:self.firstVC];
}

- (void)displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content {
// handle this problem with replacing method
[content willMoveToParentViewController:self];
// there will be wired bottom space (64px)
[self addChildViewController:content];
[self.view addSubview:content.view];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Wired Space
[image: Wired Space]

Comment: Do you adjust frame for the child VC?

Comment: @kirander NO.And,I fix it by setting the frame of child VC before  the method 'addChildViewController'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the property **edgesForExtendedLayout** caused this problem    `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;`    
Try to add this code to your project in **viewDidLoad**

Answer (score 0):

adjust your frame for your child view controller (content)

```
content.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                             width: controller.view.frame.width,
                            height: controller.view.frame.height)
```

If this doesn't fix your problem use the Debug View Hierarchy
[image]

Comment: It works.Reset the frame of child vc before the method 'addChildViewController'.